# Undefined variable: testimonial in D:\Projects\PWP-WP\wp-content\themes\blankslate-child\template-parts\fields\flex\bottom-page-block.php on line 123

Tags: permalinks, errors

In the test environment I see this error `( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: testimonial in D:\Projects\PWP-WP\wp-content\themes\blankslate-child\template-parts\fields\flex\bottom-page-block.php on line 123`. I know the reason for the error. What I need help with is how to get the right parameter to pass in the function `echo get_the_permalink($testimonial);` Below is the PHP script generating the error.

```
<?php
$image1 = get_sub_field( 'image_1' );
$image2 = get_sub_field( 'image_2' );
?>

<div class="pl pr mt-row">
  
  <div class="inside mini">

    <?php if ( $headline = get_sub_field( 'headline' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="mb">
      <h2 class="mb0 color-purple-base">
        <?php echo $headline; ?>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $text_area = get_sub_field( 'text_area' ) ) : ?>
    <article class="body-area mb">
      <?php echo $text_area; ?>
    </article>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $subheadline = get_sub_field( 'subheadline' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="mb">
      <h3 class="alt-heading mb0 h6">
        <?php echo $subheadline; ?>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div><!-- inside.mini -->

    
  <?php if($image1 || $image2): ?>
  <div class="image1-image2-wrap relative mt2x">
    <div class="row mb2x-row nested">

      <?php if($image1): ?>
      <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="bottom-image-wrap relative">
          <div class="object-cover-wrap">
            <picture>
              <source media="(max-width: 360px)" srcset="<?php echo($image1['sizes']['xsmall']); ?>">
              <source media="(max-width: 640px)" srcset="<?php echo($image1['sizes']['small']); ?>">
              <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="<?php echo($image1['sizes']['medium']); ?>">
              <source srcset="<?php echo($image1['sizes']['large']); ?>">
              <img src="<?php echo($image1['sizes']['large']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image1['alt']; ?>" />
            </picture>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if($image2): ?>
      <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="bottom-image-wrap relative">
          <div class="object-cover-wrap">
            <picture>
              <source media="(max-width: 360px)" srcset="<?php echo($image2['sizes']['xsmall']); ?>">
              <source media="(max-width: 640px)" srcset="<?php echo($image2['sizes']['small']); ?>">
              <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="<?php echo($image2['sizes']['medium']); ?>">
              <source srcset="<?php echo($image2['sizes']['large']); ?>">
              <img src="<?php echo($image2['sizes']['large']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image2['alt']; ?>" />
            </picture>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
    

  <?php if ( $link = get_sub_field( 'cta' ) ) : ?>
  <div class="inside mt2x">
    <div class="center-xs">
      <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" class="btn btn-tan" role="button" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $link['title']; ?>">
        <?php echo $link['title']; ?>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  
  <?php
  $posts = get_sub_field( 'testimonials' );
  if ( $posts ) : ?>
  <div class="inside mt-row">
    <div id="pp-testimonial" class="testimonial-box show-arrows">
      <div class="pp-quote-box center-xs relative">
        <div class="pl pr">
          <div class="pt hide-md"></div>
          <div class="pt2x hide-xs show-md"></div>
          <i class="absolute icon-quote no-touch select-none"></i>
          <div id="testimonial-slider">
            <?php foreach( $posts as $post) : ?>
            <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <div class="slide">

              <blockquote><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></blockquote>

              <?php 
              if ( $testimonial_author = get_field( 'testimonial_-_author' ) ) :
              echo "<p class='mt4 mb0'>&mdash; $testimonial_author</p>";
              endif; ?>

              <?php 
              if ( $testimonial_company = get_field( 'testimonial_-_company' ) ) :
              echo "<p class='mt2 mb0 bold caps small'>$testimonial_company</p>";
              endif; ?>

            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="pb hide-md"></div>
          <div class="pb2x hide-xs show-md"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt2x center-xs">
      <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($testimonial); ?>" class="btn" role="button">
        Read All Reviews
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Your link is outside the loop through the testimonials, and says "Read All Reviews". What do you need it to link to?

Comment: I need it to link to all testimonials page.

Comment: Is that a page? A post type archive?

Comment: It is a page on our WordPress site.

Comment: So what are you trying to set $testimonial to? If it's a page you can probably use get_page_by_path() to find it.